# Chrome keeps caching my old page until I hit the refresh button but come back next visit or few days later

Tags: angular, caching, refresh, service-worker, production-environment

I am experiencing this weird issue where my Chrome browser keeps loading a old version of my website whose code doesn't even exist on my server any more. I assume it's a typical cache issue.

I needed to hard refresh the browser cache to make it updated. but next time or few days later the old version comes back again. Anyone know why and after clear the cache and it still come back.

Comment: Ctl f5. Or f12 network tab clear cache

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by redo the same project without using service worker. With service worker on it will catching the website all the time even with all those suggested solutions from internet still can't make it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta tags to make  non cached

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Add these in your index.html or main file which gets served initially.

Comment: found the issue is causing by the service workers. After I unregistered service workers in Chrome and my website loading the new version every time now in Chrome but it still loading the old version first load in other browsers. As I know service workers are designed to check every 24 hours to see if there is a newer version available but it failed to do so.